# Change progress bar color depending on the value

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app where I use a server to make tasks and then you can change the progress of your task from 0 to 100, but putting my progress bar a simple color seems a little too less. I wanna know if it is possible to let's say under it starts red, the more it get close to 50 the more it gets yellow, and the more it gets to 100 it gets green. Is that something that is even possible?

I already set the color of my progress bar trough my code but I can't seem to find any method that will allows me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `horizontal ProgressBar`, you can use a `ColorFilter` as follows:

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
 Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

You need to add the logic as described by you to set the respective color.

Since `Lollipop (API 21)` you can set a progress tint:

```
progressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

**UPDATE**

For pre-lollipop versions you can do something like:

```
ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
int color = 0xFF00FF00;
progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Hope that helps!